# Save temporary object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a client application, written using wpf.

How should I retain or update some object throughout the application life span.

Is there any method to store some object like:

1. Store store = new Store(); So that I can access of update the object throughout the application windows.
2. String, int, boolean.

Thank you.

Comment: Very difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. But if you are using WPF you may use the Application class and access variables through Application.Current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
 Application.Current.Properties["PropertyName"]
```

to store properties, globally.

Answer (score 3):

You can define these variables in App.xaml.cs file i.e. within Application class as shown below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}
}
```

And then, you can access these variables from other windows like:

```
    var app = (App) Application.Current;
    MessageBox.Show(app.Fullname);
```

This will allow you access/modify your variables.
Hope this helps.

Comment: that's very clever way